# AngularJS - How do I get the property being sorted? I'm trying to force all nulls to the bottom when sorting on the header of a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here are some code snippets:

```
...
<th class="header" ng-click="sortType = 'ProjectCode'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
   <span ng-show="sortType == 'ProjectCode' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
   <span ng-show="sortType == 'ProjectCode' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
   Code
</th>
<th class="header" ng-click="sortType = 'ProjectName'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
   <span ng-show="sortType == 'ProjectName' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
   <span ng-show="sortType == 'ProjectName' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
   Project Name
</th>
...
<tr ng-repeat="collection in filteredCollections = (collections | filter:collectionFilter | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse)" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
```

So, in my ng-repeat is there any way that I can get the `sortType` property from the header?

I'm ***not*** trying to send all nulls of a default property to the end of the list on load. Rather, every time I click a table header, I want to grab that property about to be sorted, and deal with the nulls in my Angular app (send all nulls of that property to end of array). For each header in the table.
Or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I declared a filter in the Angular app:

```
app.filter("emptyToEnd", function () {
    return function (array, key) {
    if(!angular.isArray(array)) return;
         var present = array.filter(function (item) {
            return item[key];
         });

         var empty = array.filter(function (item) {
            return !item[key]
         });

         return present.concat(empty);
     };
});
```

And added  `| emptyToEnd:sortType` to the end of my ng-repeat